# Evaluar si una lista de Strings contiene un numero en java

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con una lista que contiene urls que deben ser excluidas en un filtro.

```
List<String> excludeFromFilter = Arrays.asList(ApiResources.Account_LOGIN,
        ApiResources.Account.URI_GET_MERCHANT,
        ApiResources.Account.URI_GET_ACCOUNT);
```

En seguida para la funcionalidad evalúo si `excludeFromFilter` contine la url que le paso por el request:

```
final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
final String path = request.getPathInfo();

if (!excludeFromFilter.contains(path)) {
   ...
}
```

El problema es que en ocasiones debo verificar que esté excluida una url que contiene un parámetro, por ejemplo: `/api/accounts/24`qué correspondería a la constante `ApiResources.Account.URI_GET_ACCOUNT` que tiene como valor `/api/accounts/{accountId}`. No puedo reemplazar el 24 con {accountId} para la validación porque más adelante puedo necesitar excluir una url que contenga otro parámetro, por ejemplo `/api/accounts/{merchantId}`.

Cómo puedo utilizar la función contains() para qué valide si la url tiene cualquier número en ese parámetro. Actualmente así luce la lista:

[/user/login, /api/merchants/{merchantId}, /api/accounts/{accountId}]

y para este último valor debería ser `true` la función contains() con valores como: `"/api/accounts/24"`, `"/api/accounts/1"`, `"/api/accounts/130"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no lo lograrás con `List#contains`. Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar un grupo de patrones de regexps y buscar si alguno de ellos hace match con la cadena (url) que necesitas evaluar.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
List<Pattern> listaRegex = asList(
    Pattern.compile(ApiResources.Account_LOGIN),
    Pattern.compile(ApiResources.Account.URI_GET_MERCHANT),
    Pattern.compile(ApiResources.Account.URI_GET_ACCOUNT)
);
```

Asumiendo que estas cadenas tienen valores similares a (el regex puede ser más complejo, dependiendo de lo que necesites)):

```
[/user/login, /api/merchants/\d*, /api/accounts/\d*]
```

Y reemplazar en tu método esta parte:

```
if (!excludeFromFilter.contains(path)) {
    ...
}
```

por:

```
if (shouldBeExcluded(path)) {
    //...
}
```

Asimismo, declaras el método `shouldBeExcluded`.

Java 8:

```
boolean shouldBeExcluded(String path) {
    return listaRegex.stream() //convertir a Stream
        .filter(p -> p.matcher(path).matches() ) //filtrar aquellos que cumplan con el patrón de regex y evaluar que el regex hace match con la url que indicas
        .findFirst() //devuelve el primer elemento en el stream luego de aplicar el filtro. Acción lazy, es decir, no evalúa todos los elementos para obtener el primero, al encontrar uno se detiene. Esto devuelve un Optional.
        .isPresent(); //verificar si existe un elemento devuelvo
}
```

Java 7 o pre:

```
boolean shouldBeExcluded(String path) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (Pattern pattern : listaRegex) {
        if (pattern.matcher(path).matches()) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Luiggi, disculpa una pregunta esto funciona para Java 1.8, el proyecto en el que trabajo debe trabajar con Java 1.7. Conoces alguna alternativa?

Comment: @AndreFontaine actualizado

Comment: Si se desea ganar algunos *nanosegundos/milisegundos*... ① Cada instancia de `Pattern` debería compilarse una vez. Por ejemplo, al inicio de la aplicación. ② La versión para Java 7 de `shouldBeExcluded` es más veloz que la versión de Java 8, tal como están *plasmadas* aquí. ☺

Comment: @PaulVargas no veo el enlace para el punto ②